# How to launch app in floating mode in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I programmatically launch my flutter app in a popup window as shown in the picture. In this mode, interactivity should be preserved, the entire program is active, and not just 1 widget. Android only.[screenshot of floating window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7RDF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best library to solve my problem. This is exactly what I was looking for. The library is used to launch the application in a popup window with all the interactivity. [android_window](https://pub.dev/packages/android_window)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [flutter_android_pip](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_android_pip) package ? 
It doesn't support null safety, which could cause some problems. It also only supports Android, but that doesn't seem to be a problem according to what you asked.

Comment: Yes, I did. It has no interaction just maximize or close button